# What does Key stand for?

Tags: java, android

what should I do if I want call this class. And what is the Key stands for.

```java
 public static final Key<StreamConfigurationMap> SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP
```

Comment: Did you get that from a doc? can you give some more context? I assume you added the `**` yourself?

Comment: The Key part is the name of the class, the following <StreamConfigurationMap> part is a [Generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Comment: Does that mean it I have to write public static final streamConfig as a name for example...  <StreamConfigurationMap> ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [doc for the CameraCharacteristics class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics), you have the following attribute:

```
public static final Key<StreamConfigurationMap> SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP
```

> The available stream configurations that this camera device supports; also includes the minimum frame durations and the stall durations for each format/size combination.

This attribute is of type `android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics.Key<T>`. It is a `Generic` type where `T` is a placeholder for a type. In our case the type `T` is [StreamConfigurationMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap)

Here is [the doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.Key.html) for class `Key<T>`

So `SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP` is a static field of `CameraCharacteristics` and it can be accessed this way:

```
CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP
```

and it is of type `Key<T>` where `T` is `StreamConfigurationMap`

Comment: @AliA you can upvote and accept the answer if that is what you wanted to know